# Copy-on-write pointer object in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, copy-on-write

I tried to follow this article
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-on-write on how to implement copy on write pointers in C++. The problem is, it doesn't work for me.

The crux of the object is in overloading the dereference operator (*) to do background copying if it should return a non-const reference:

```
   const T& operator*() const
    {
        return *m_sp;
    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        detach();
        return *m_sp;
    }
```

Sadly, it seems that only the second version is ever run.
C-outing the my pointed-to object creates a copy, even doing something like

```
   CowPtr<string> my_cow_ptr(new string("hello world"));
   const string& const_ref=*my_cow_ptr;
```

causes the `detach()` function to run.

Any ideas on why it's not working as advertised?

Comment: This is *not* copy-on-write (even if this worked).

Comment: Can you show some more context? How do you declare your `my_cow_ptr`?

Comment: @Andy Prowl: I expanded the second snippet for you. CowPtr id defined in the link.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Well, technically it's copy-on-returning-a-non-const-reference. But that's splitting hairs.

Comment: Perhaps whoever advertised it had no flying idea what he was talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `const` member function will be called on a `const` object. so:

```
const CowPtr<std::string> my_const_cow_ptr(new std::string("Hello, world"));
const std::string& str = *my_const_cow_ptr;
```

or

```
CowPtr<std::string> my_cow_ptr(new std::string("Hello, world"));
const std::string& str = *static_cast<const CowPtr<std::string>&>(my_cow_ptr);
```

Comment: But that also means that aside of const-casting, on every call, there is no way the compiler will know to call each function automatically... so the whole point of copy-on-write goes down the drain.